# Qt Designer custom dialog template

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have created custom dialog class that inherits from `QDialog`. I would like to use it in a Qt Designer.

However there is a problem, as I do not know how to add it to the templates, that I could pick, when I select File/new.
I also tried to start with `QDialog` and then promote it to my custom class, however context menu on the form does not give me option to promote or change type of the form.

Is there a solution to this problem which does not include manually tweaking generated `.ui` file ?

Comment: the simplest solution is to edit the .ui, the other would be to create a plugin for that widget for QtDesigner. Why do not you want to use the first solution?

Comment: To promote the normal `QWidget` to your custom class, you need to add the `QWidget` to the `.ui` file, right click and select `Promoted Widgets`. Then add your custom class manually to the list with appropriate information. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets

Comment: I have tried creating custom widgets in the past but have had little success. However, I do know that you need to create a plugin project for this. This example could help: https://www.ics.com/blog/integrating-custom-widget-qt-designer